# How to get total Like, Share, and Comment count for various Facebook post types?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I am creating a simple CMS system whereby users can contribute inspirational posts made by brand pages on Facebook.  All the user has to do is paste in a permalink to a post and the CMS will handle pinging the Graph API in order to acquire all the info it needs.  (e.g. https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10152047553868306&set=a.99394368305.88399.40796308305&type=1&relevant_count=1)

One of the requirements of the CMS is that `like`, `comment`, and `share` counts are included for each post.  This is where I struggle.

Simply pinging the graph endpoint with a photo ID will only return a paginated list of likes/comments.  There is no parameter for total likes or total comments.  Fortunately, the `photo` table includes `like_info` and `comment_info` members for me to query upon.  This works great for getting totals on photos:

`SELECT like_info, comment_info FROM photo WHERE object_id = 10152047553868306`

One would expect then that I could apply the same FQL `SELECT` on the `status` or `video` tables in order to get the `like` and `comment` info for status updates and video posts but you cannot.  `like_info` and `comment_info` only reside on the `photo` table.

At least right now I can get like/comment total for photos, but I still see no indication on how to get share totals for a photo.

Is there a way I can reliably acquire `like`, `comment`, and `share` counts for video posts, photo posts, and status posts? Using any combination of Graph or FQL API?

Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I have found something like this for facebook graph api v2.8

```
$accessToken ="XXXXXXXXXX";

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook(array(
        'app_id' => 'Facbook App Id',
        'app_secret' =>  'Facebook Secret Key',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
)); 

$params = array();

$request = $fb->request('GET', '/{post_id}/?fields=likes.limit(0).summary(true),comments.limit(0).summary(true)',$params,$accessToken);

$response = $fb->getClient()->sendRequest($request);

$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
$likeArr = $graphNode['likes']->getMetaData();
$commentArr = $graphNode['comments']->getMetaData();

echo "Total Post Likes : ".$likeArr['summary']['total_count'];
echo "Total Post Comments : ".$commentArr['summary']['total_count'];
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id=10151751324059927 LIMIT 1000
```